# 45Mb table takes ~5Gb bytes written to insert data PHP SQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, memory-leaks

Trying to insert 1 000 000 lines (each line is 10 chars) which takes about 140 seconds with the execute command or 48 seconds with the commit command. Once it's done the table weight is 45Mb, but Activity Monitor said that mysqld took 5Gb and that written speed was ~40Mb/second. Another instance: A day ago when I was doing the same, but 30 000 000 lines (1.3Gb in phpMyAdmin), but Activity Monitor said mysqld wrote 950Gb(~1Tb).
So my question is what is going on here? I mean I don't feel like killing my SSD...

```
MAMP 5.7 (396)
macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H114)
MacBook Pro 13" 2019 SSD 256Gb RAM 8Gb
running code through terminal
```

- 

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:8889;dbname=my', $user, $password);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test1` ( `ID` char(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );";
$dbh->exec($sql);
$handle = fopen("./lines/30000000.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
  while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
     $trimmed_line = trim($line);
     $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO `test1` SET `ID` = :ID");
     $sth->execute(array('ID' => $trimmed_line));
  }
  fclose($handle); 
}

     //or in the while loop
     array_push($array_of_lines, $trimmed_line);
     if (count($array_of_lines) >= 3000) {
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO test1 SET ID = :ID");
        $dbh->beginTransaction();
        foreach ($array_of_lines as $line) {
           $sth->execute(['ID' => $line]);
        }
        $dbh->commit();
        $array_of_lines = [];
     }
   }
   if (count($array_of_lines)) {
      //commit the last lines
   }
```

30000000.txt looks like this:

```
owehfowffu
lrehgeorhw
lirewkhfwe
idhfwuiefo
...
30 000 000 unique lines
```

[phpMyAdmin 47.6Mb 1 000 000 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDb1y.png)

[Activity Monitor 2.9Gb and 33Mb/sec while inserting 47.6mb 1 000 000 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fixl9.png)

Comment: This might come from over-indexed tables?

Comment: @B001ᛦ In the txt file each line is unique.

Comment: _..In the txt file each line is unique..._ I talked about the db table...I'd go and check the indices there... also keep in mind that its not a good idea to set the primary key type to char. Under the hood the primary key will be added to each column of the table and increase the data size

Comment: @B001ᛦ I'm not sure what I'm supposed to look at. For instance, I expanded my test1 table to see Columns (New, ID) and Indexes (New, PRIMARY).

Comment: @B001ᛦ Also there is another thing that freaks me out. When I open the table (phpMyAdmin) and press Browse to see the rows it says that there are 1136972 rows in total despite the fact that I inserted only 1 000 000. Also when I chose the last page from the list there are no data available (empty rows), so I have to chose a proper page and once I chose the proper one it will show the actual last lines and say 1000000 rows in total...

Comment: @B001ᛦ Well I tried the same, but with the table that has INT(11) as a primary key and CHAR(10) to store the lines. This time phpMyAdmin says that the 1 000 000 table size is 34.6Mb (instead of 47.6Mb), Activity Monitor says that mysqld wrote 190Mb (instead of ~5Gb) and 3-5Mb/second writing speed during 48 second inserting of data. Also that freaking me out thing of total rows seems to be fixed. Anyways, it took 190Mb to make the 35Mb table. Is it okay?

Comment: _...it says that there are 1136972 rows in total ..._ This is just an estimation

Comment: _..Is it okay? .._ I'd say yeah! have fun

Comment: @B001ᛦ When it was 1136972 rows in total and I was able to find the actual last page from the list the total value was changed to the actual size of 1000000 rows in total, but now there are no empty pages and it always shows 998412 rows in total, but I had inserted 1000000 and $dbh->query('select count(*) from test1')->fetchColumn() returns 1000000. So is it still an estimation and those "Showing rows 998400 - 998411" are actually the last lines of that million? It does not seem to be true, because the last ID on the last page is 998500.

Comment: @B001ᛦ It is so weird, it says 998412 rows in total, 998500 as a last ID of the table on the last page, but I am able to SELECT 1000000 ID and get it's value. Anyway, the last thing that is still bothering me is that mysqld writes ~200Mb when the table size is 35Mb. I mean it would write 6Gb to get 1Gb table once I insert 30 000 000 rows. Of course, it's not 950Gb that I had, but it's still something frustrating.